# Extract product type from a free text product description

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm looking to extract **product type** from a **free text product description** for grouping purposes.

The context is a learning exercise from an old Kaggel competition (mercari-price-suggestion-challenge).

Google / Stack Overflow offers multiple directions, but no specific out-of-the-box code (I could find).

The best I was able to come up with (I'm an NLP newbie) is via **spacy** package, parse the product name description, and take the ROOT word as the product type itself, **please see code below**.

The solution seems to provide fair results sometimes, please see results sample below, but I think there should be a better practice for an off the shelf code.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

z = train_data
z = z.assign(product_enitity=z['name'].apply(nlp))
z = z.assign(product_enitity_parse=[([(X, X.dep_) for X in Y]) for Y in z['product_enitity']])

def get_root_word(sent):
    return [tok[0] for tok in sent if (tok[1] == "ROOT") ]

z = z.assign(root_product_name=[get_root_word(sent) for sent in z['product_enitity_parse']])
```

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name | product_enitity_parse | root_product_name |
| Air Jordan Retro 6 Sport Blue | [(Air, compound), (Jordan, compound), (Retro, ROOT), (6, nummod), (Sport, compound), (Blue, appos)] | [Retro] |
| Salvatore Ferragamo Belt FREE SHIPPING | [(Salvatore, amod), (Ferragamo, compound), (Belt, npadvmod), (FREE, amod), (SHIPPING, ROOT)] | [SHIPPING] |
| Raspberry Cherokee Scrubs top and pants. | [(Raspberry, compound), (Cherokee, compound), (Scrubs, nsubj), (top, ROOT), (and, cc), (pants, c... | [top] |
| Uggs size 7 | [(Uggs, compound), (size, ROOT), (7, nummod)] | [size] |
| Essential Oil Diffuser | [(Essential, amod), (Oil, compound), (Diffuser, ROOT)] | [Diffuser] |
| Skylanders | [(Skylanders, ROOT)] | [Skylanders] |
| Sono human hair extensions 20 inches | [(Sono, nmod), (human, amod), (hair, nsubj), (extensions, ROOT), (20, nummod), (inches, npadvmod)] | [extensions] |
| NWT LulaRoe Girls Mae Dress Size 4 | [(NWT, compound), (LulaRoe, compound), (Girls, compound), (Mae, compound), (Dress, compound), (S... | [Size] |
| ES Bra and Panty set of 4 (36B) | [(ES, compound), (Bra, nmod), (and, cc), (Panty, conj), (set, ROOT), (of, prep), (4, pobj), ((, ... | [set] |
| Free Shipping Skeleton Kids Top | [(Free, amod), (Shipping, compound), (Skeleton, compound), (Kids, compound), (Top, ROOT)] | [Top] |

Answer (score 0):

Determining product type is a classification, not an extraction task. If the product title is "Nintendo Switch Red Blue New in Box" the category could be "video games".

In your dataset it looks like there is a "category_name" field, that's your label. You should look at using the [textcat](https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer) model in spaCy, see the [example projects](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials).

Comment: thanks! pls see I'm not looking for product category (category & brand is offered within the data via additional columns), but for product itself - I think in the example you provided the answer would be "Nintendo Switch"
I'm under the impression that this may not be a classification task for the following two reasons: [1] the answer is within the sentence (mostly) [2] there are _many_ different products.

Comment: OK, that is a different task. I honestly don't think it'll work, my impression is the "product name" is often not in the title, or it will be highly inconsistent. Either way, ecommerce titles are not grammatical sentences so dependency parsers won't help you much.

Comment: Maybe see this paper, where they extract brand treating it as a sequence labelling (NER) task. I guess you could try it. https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Attribute-Extraction-from-Product-Titles-in-More/e6d2a841960e62205f1cab81669392c7fa430340